# reformatting dplyr summarise_at() output

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `summarise_at()` to obtain the mean and standard error of multiple variables by group.

The output has 1 row for each group, and 1 column for each calculated quantity, per group. I'd like to have a table with 1 row for each variable, and 1 column for each calculated quantity:

```
data <- mtcars 

data$condition <- as.factor(c(rep("control", 16), rep("treat", 16))) 

data %>%  
group_by(condition) %>%
summarise_at(vars(mpg, cyl, wt), 
             funs(mean = mean, se=sd(.)/sqrt(n())))

# A tibble: 2 x 7
    condition mpg_mean cyl_mean wt_mean mpg_se cyl_se wt_se
    <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>        
  1 control       18.2     6.5     3.56   1.04  0.387 0.204
  2 treat         22.0     5.88    2.87   1.77  0.499 0.257
```

Here's what I think would be more useful (the numbers are not meaningful):

```
#        MEAN.control, MEAN.treat, SE.control, SE.treat
# mpg         1.5          2.4         .30       .45             
# cyl         3.2          1.9         .20       .60  
# disp        12.3         17.8        .20       .19
```

Any ideas? New to the `tidyverse`, so sorry if this is too basic.

Answer (score 5):

The `funs` is getting deprecated in `dplyr`.  Instead use `list` in `summarise_at/mutate_at`.  After the `summarise` step, `gather` the data into 'long' format, `separate` the 'key' column into two by splitting at the delimiter `_`, then `unite` the 'cond' and 'key2' (after changing the case of 'key2'), `spread` it to 'wide' format and if needed, change the row names with the column 'key1'

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   group_by(condition) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(mpg, cyl, wt), list(MEAN = ~ mean(.), 
                                    SE = ~sd(.)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
   gather(key, val, -condition) %>% 
   separate(key, into = c("key1", "key2")) %>%        
   unite(cond, key2, condition, sep=".") %>% 
   spread(cond, val) %>%
   column_to_rownames('key1')
#    MEAN.control MEAN.treat SE.control  SE.treat
#cyl     6.500000   5.875000  0.3872983 0.4989572
#mpg    18.200000  21.981250  1.0369024 1.7720332
#wt      3.560875   2.873625  0.2044885 0.2571034
```

Comment: Curious, why was `funs` changed to `list`?!

Comment: @NelsonGon I find an open issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3932) but the reason is not mentioned

Comment: thank you!! I updated the example in light of your comment as well. I appreciate it.

Comment: @BrianGuay  Thanks for the update.  But, I see the values are different.  Is this the expected output

Answer (score 3):

A different possibility could be:

```
data %>%  
 group_by(condition) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(mpg, cyl, wt), list(mean = ~ mean(.), 
                                       se = ~ sd(.)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
 gather(var, val, -condition) %>%
 separate(var, c("vars", "var2")) %>%
 mutate(var2 = paste(toupper(var2), as.character(condition), sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-condition) %>%
 spread(var2, val)

  vars  MEAN_control MEAN_treat SE_control SE_treat
  <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 cyl           6.5        5.88      0.387    0.499
2 mpg          18.2       22.0       1.04     1.77 
3 wt            3.56       2.87      0.204    0.257
```

Here, after your initial steps, it performs a wide-to-long data transformation, excluding the "condition" column. Second, it separates the variable names into two columns. Third, it combines the metric and the condition, with the metric being upper case. Finally, it removes the redundant variable and returns it to the desired format.

Or you can avoid `separate()` by using some regex:

```
data %>%  
 group_by(condition) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(mpg, cyl, wt), list(mean = ~ mean(.), 
                                       se = ~ sd(.)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
 gather(var, val, -condition) %>%
 mutate(vars = gsub("_.*$", "", var),
        var2 = gsub(".*\\_", "", var)) %>%
 mutate(var2 = paste(toupper(var2), as.character(condition), sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-condition, -var) %>%
 spread(var2, val)
```

Or with `strsplit()`:

```
data %>%  
 group_by(condition) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(mpg, cyl, wt), list(mean = ~ mean(.), 
                                       se = ~ sd(.)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
 gather(var, val, -condition) %>%
 mutate(vars = sapply(strsplit(var, "_"), function(x) x[1]),
        var2 = sapply(strsplit(var, "_"), function(x) x[2])) %>%
 mutate(var2 = paste(toupper(var2), as.character(condition), sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-condition, -var) %>%
 spread(var2, val)
```

Or you can completely rewrite it to:

```
data %>%
 select(mpg, cyl, wt, condition) %>%
 gather(vars, val, -condition) %>%
 group_by(condition, vars) %>%
 summarise(mean = mean(val),
           se = sd(val)/sqrt(n())) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 gather(var2, val, -c(condition, vars)) %>%
 mutate(var2 = paste(toupper(var2), condition, sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-condition) %>%
 spread(var2, val)
```

In this case it, first, selects the variables of interest. Second, it performs a transformation from wide to long format, excluding the "condition" column. Third, it groups by conditions and variable names and calculates the metrics. In the forth step, it performs a second wide-to-long transformation, excluding the "condition" column and the column with initial variable names. Finally, it combines together the metric (upper case) and condition, removes the redundant variable and returns it to the desired format.